# Multiple exogenous IV 2sls in Stata

Tags: regression, time-series, stata, instrumental-variables, 2sls

In my model I have two exogenous variables which I want to use as instruments.
Can you please help me with Stata code for it?
I assume it should be something like this:

```
ivregress 2sls inf exp_inf gap (brent gas = oil_lag1 gas_lag1)
```

where first instrument is `brent=oil_lag1` 
and second is `gas=gas_lag1`

Am I right? I just got strange results so I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

The endogenous variables that you want to instrument for go on the left of the equal sign and the instruments go on the right side in the parenthetical part.

The intuition behind 2SLS is that you are using the instruments to predict the endogenous variables, and using the predictions from that model as regressors in place of the endogenous variables themselves. In the first stage, the endogenous variables are the outcome variable and instruments are the explanatory variables or regressors. The parenthetical part represents that first stage.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Actually, I am trying to instrument variable by it`s lag. I run Lag-order selection statistics and it strongly suggests me that I should use first lag for my model. However, when I include this lag, all the variables become insignificant. So model doesn't tell me anything.

Can you suggest something?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: @VictoriiaAlekhina I don't really understand your model and this is not my area of expertise. There's also not very much detail in your questions, so you are unlikely to get much useful advice from anyone else. I suggest asking a new question on the [econ SE site](http://economics.stackexchange.com/), where you provde some additonal details (what is the outcome, what is the source of endogeneity, why are the isntruments relevant and exogenous, how did you implement the lag selection, etc.)